# How to achieve less repetitive Helm naming?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When releasing a Helm chart, Kubernetes resources have Helm's `.Release.Name` prepended to their names. In the Chart I'm writing separate namespaces with default resource naming is enough, and the additional prefix is verbose and unwanted. Vault is a dependency of my Chart.

Is there a way I can achieve this using Helm? Ideally, I should only be able to deploy this chart once per namespace, supplying a namespace and release name also feel redundant.

```bash
# Specify namespace and release name
helm install --create-namespace -n my-namespace my-release hashicorp/vault

# Vault is named "my-release-vault-..." 
kubectl get svc -n my-namespace
NAME                                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
my-release-vault                      ClusterIP   10.98.169.234    <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP   8s
```

Comment: The answer depends on which chart you're deploying, the name of the resources are decided by the structure of the templates in the chart. 

Quite likely, the charts have an option to override the name, usually with `.Values.nameOverride`. Check for the options in your chart values yaml to validate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick look at the Chart and I don't think there is the possibility of doing what is requested.

What you can do is modify the templates yourself, adding the override parameter for names/namespaces and try doing a PR against the Hashicorp repo; maybe they didn't think this feature could be useful.

Otherwise, you simply create a custom CHANGELOG where you track all these changes that remind you that you have to make changes to the repository every time you download a new version. It's a maintenance job you won't ignore, but it often happens in Enterprise and highly customized environments that you have to modify the Vendor templates.

This is where the definition of the name happens:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hashicorp/vault-helm/main/templates/_helpers.tpl
(First block)